# Core Bot C# - MS Teams: How to "Forget" Oath login user

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I use "OAuth Connection Settings" to authorize in my system but I can't relogin to a different user.
I call SignOutUserAsync of OAuthPrompt but when I try to login it uses the old one (user name & pass) and doesn't ask me about new user name & pass.
And ... I can see that my API doesn't relogin (still uses prev session).

Comment: Dont know anything about the framework but why dont you just de-authorize the session in your system? In case this is possible? Seems like a valid approach to me

Comment: de-authorize? When? It can't "de-authorize" himself. Just by request but ... Bot doesn't know the system. It uses Azure functionality and question about OAuthPrompt (Azure side)

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Right. MS Teams doesn't ask me user name and doesn't show me login form. (open and close in one moment)... I  called SignOutUser and token is null after that but I can't use a different user name for my system.

Comment: Did you use SSO for your bot? also Could you please try by cleaning the cache and uninstall all the instances of the app and reinstall the bot again? Try if that helps.

Comment: I use "OAuth Connection Settings" to authorize in my system +  OAuthPrompt dialog. Cache? What kind og cache?

Comment: When you use the SSO for your application it will ask for the credentials for the first time only. This is by design.

Comment: But ... It requests the user again after period of time .

Answer (score 0):

I think behind the scenes the Bot Framework is caching the credential for you, which in ordinary events would be useful, but not for what you're trying to do here of course. Nevertheless, while you don't mention what platform you're using, in dotnet, using `Microsoft.Bot.Builder`, there is a `BotFrameworkAdapter` class that would exist in your project. `BotFrameworkAdapter` has a `SignOutUserAsync` method which I would think would do what you need. I'm pretty sure there's an equivalent in Node.js as well.